# TempData empty when redirect to other url than root, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this method.

```
        public ActionResult SetTempDataToChangeVendor(int vendorId, string url)
        {            
            TempData["ChangeVendor"] = vendorId;
            if (url == null) return Redirect("/");

            var slug = _urlRecordRepository.Table.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Slug == url);

            if (slug == null) RedirectToAction("PageNotFound", "Common");

            return Redirect("/" + url);
        }
```

It works just fine when it redirects to /. But when a url i supplied the TempData is empty, and I can't understand why.

Comment: You didn't make yourself very clear. Can you please elaborate what problem do you have ? What is your question about ?

Comment: It should work. Are you sure you are not reading it already somewhere ? Once read, TempData will be empty

Comment: I just remembered, we have a custom routing controller, so it will actually be two redirects when redirecting to the url. Think I can fix this by reading it in the routing controller and using the keep method. Thanks anyway and sorry for the vague question.

Answer (score 0):

**TempData** is a bucket where you can dump data that is only needed for the following request. That is, anything you put into **TempData** is discarded after the next request completes.

Comment: `TempData` should still work for a redirect until it is read.